# Beautifulsoup interprets @ in smiles data as [email protected] by mistake. How can I have the basic string?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have pages with smiles data representing chemical formulas like that :

```
C/C=C\1/C(=O)N[C@H](C(=O)O[C@H]\2CC(=O)N[C@@H](C(=O)N[C@H](CSSCC/C=C2)C(=O)N1)C(C)C)C(C)C
```

When I try scraping the data, beautifulsoup interprets [C@H] as a protected email. I don't need to decrypt the email, and there is not real protect, just a wrong interpretation of it as a mail (I guess, there is not reason to protect this.

I there a way to tell beautifulsoup that despite the @ sign, this is not an email and to just get the basic string?

(about smiles : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system)

Comment: what you have tried so far

Comment: works fine for me. could you provide more context?

Comment: Yes, for example in a page like this : https://www.adooq.com/vx-765.html. Inspecting the page gives me the correct string, but going trough requests + beautifulSoup will get me some [[protected mail]] string when a @ is present

Comment: it's not beautifulsoup, it's the server that sends data this way. easy to solve with `str.replace` though